# What's this kind of periodical with harder, superior writing called?

Tags: word-choice

To improve my critical reading and thinking skills, I'm trying to find magazines/periodicals with these traits. Please advise as to what they're named, so that I know for what to search?

1. Style and quality of writing must be more sophisticated, intricate, pre-eminent style and quality of writing, but still readable, lucid, and enjoyable. I want familiarity and acquaintance with this so that I'll better understand denser, more abstract writing in general, which I'll confront.

2. Topics should involve debatable global topics on general principles, so that I can learn about and evaluate equally strong, effective, cogent arguments on both sides. For example, I'm more interested in psychology, applied philosophy, law, economics, current affairs that affect someone in both North America and the UK. I want to avoid content on literature or politics (that relate only to a specific country).

3. I prefer US, UK, or Canadian, but the periodical can be weekly or even monthly, and not just daily.

I recognise the term 'broadsheet', but it doesn't depict the above, because The Telegraph and even The Guardian are biased. The Economist seems better, which isn't truly described by the aforesaid terms. My English needs cultivation, so I can't determine if The Spectator or the New Statesman fit?

Comment: I don't think there is a specific *name* (= *word*) for what you are describing, unless it is *journal.*... But if you are asking for recommendations of specific periodicals/journals/magazines/broadsheets to read, I am not sure that is on topic because you are asking for opinions.

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic as primarily opinion based. There's a fairly straightforward set of criteria listed, and while we might argue whether a _specific_ periodical is "sophisticated writing but enjoyable reading", I think we can come up with some suggestions for periodicals that might be useful for advanced learners.

Comment: *Magazine* is another word describing such publications, but it doesn't have any particular connotations as to the quality of the content.

Comment: If you are trying to improve your English and perhaps also your thinking or your knowledge, then it is *not important whether what you read is biased*. You are presumably looking to understand, not just to form an opinion or be persuaded.

Comment: I also consulted http://qr.ae/xYBVV

Answer (score 1):

I think it is marginally on topic to the extent that it is asking for journals that use the language lucidly.  Here are a few:

```
The Economist
The Atlantic
Mother Jones
Harpers
```

I don't know if the category has a name.